# Is there a way to curve Flatlist around the corners?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

i want to develop this view but i can't bend the flatlist and i also want to shadow the images other then the center one.i tried giving the border radius to the parent view and the flat list itself but it is not working for me
The required view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPNoe.jpg)

My View:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8RXI.png)

here is my code:
...

```
`
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';

const List = () => {
  const image= <View style={{alignItems:'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
  width:100,
  height:100,
  backgroundColor:'red',
  borderRadius:50,}}/>
  const friends = [
    {name: image, Age: '20'},
    {name: image, Age: '45'},
    {name: image, Age: '30'},
    {name: image, Age: '37'},
    {name: image, Age: '90'},
    {name: image, Age: '200'},
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.listStyle}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={friend => friend.Age}
        data={friends}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <Text style={styles.textpro}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle:{
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'white',
        flex:1
        },
    listStyle:{
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'red',
        borderRadius:100,
        flex:1,
    },
  op: {
    height: 10,
    width: 10,
    color: '#00ffff',
  },
});
export default List;
//App.js code
<View style={{backgroundColor:'rgb(50,117,220)',height:'30%',backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
        <List />
</View>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

someone asked me to try react native snap carousel and it worked like a charm idk why he deleted his comment.I feel blessed <3

Comment: you can close this question if you found the answer